# Падеж существительного после глагола «уменьшать»

Tags: грамматика, падежи, управление, родительный-или-винительный

Поймал себя на мысли, что второе предложение неверное. Но почему тогда четвертое, на мой взгляд, допустимое?

1. Его речь уменьшает мои заслуги.
2. Его речь уменьшает моих заслуг.
3. Его речь не уменьшает мои заслуги.
4. Его речь не уменьшает моих заслуг.

Comment: Такова грамматика русского языка. Что тут ещё можно сказать? Если есть отрицание при слове ‟уменьшать”, то существительные, которыми управляет это слово, можно ставить как в родительный, так и винительный падеж.

Comment: А где об этом сказано в официальных источниках?

Comment: В учебниках для носителей языка такое не пишут, так как нет смысла преподавать грамматику тому, кто её знает. Зачем носителю языка сообщать какие-то тонкости использования падежей, когда он и так это знает. Такое указывают в учебниках или словарях для изучающих русский как иностранный

Comment: Странная логика.

Comment: Об этом много написано. Вот, например: [**Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67) (Грамота.ру)

Answer (score 1):

"Уменьшать" (что делать?) — это переходный глагол несовершенного вида (см. ["уменьшить"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), сов., перех.), который управляет винительным падежом.
Правильно: *уменьшает* (что?) *мои заслуги* (второе предложение не является верным).

*Его речь не уменьшает **мои заслуги.***

Выбирая падеж [при отрицании](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67) (повторю ссылку — вдруг комментарий исчезнет), я бы предпочла тоже винительный, основываясь вот на этой рекомендации его выбора:
при наличии в предложении **местоимений**, указывающих на определенность объекта (*Ростов, не желая навязывать **свое знакомство**, не пошел в дом* (Л. Толст.)).

*Свет практически не уменьшил **мои опасения**, поскольку помимо собственно боя я увидел давившие на нас сотни* (Майкл Г. Мэннинг. Рожденный магом).
*Как я уже упоминала, я теперь гордая хозяйка почти собственной квартиры, но это не уменьшает **мои расходы*** (М. Макл. Дневник стюардессы).
*Он будил узника, чтоб тот не уснул и тем не уменьшил **свои страдания*** (Г. Дюсимбиев. Движущиеся подземелья).